# Disable a boost unit test in 1.54.0

Tags: boost

I am wondering if there is a way to skip a unit test in boost? I am aware of the macro `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` and passing in `* boost::unit_test::disabled()` however this doesn't seem to be an option in boost 1.54.0 and on compile I recieve:

```
error: macro "BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
```

and I am passing the test as such:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SOME_TEST, * boost::unit_test::disabled())
```

Answer (score 0):

Boost 1.54 doesn't have that feature (it is old - July 2013).

However you can still filter test-cases using the command line interface (CLI):

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html